# Looking for a better way to write CSVs

Tags: powershell, logic, export-to-csv

I have written a couple of PowerShell scripts to gather some statistics from a windows machine. The first one was about gathering CPU, memory usage etc. at certain intervals. Which works fine. I have written another one that basically checks lastaccesstime for files and creates a CSV, code below:

```cs
$dest="C:\users\Administrator\Documents\filelist.csv"
$csvdata=@()
$source="x:\"
$count=0

Get-ChildItem -Recurse $source | foreach{

$csvdata += New-Object PSObject -Property @{FileName=$_.FullName;DateAccessed=($_.LastAccessTime).ToShortDateString()}

$csvdata|Export-Csv $dest -notype

$count+=1
$count

}
```

Alright so if I keep adding things to `$csvdata` and only export file when the loop ends then there is a possibility I might lose data if script ends due to some error or something. So instead I export it within the loop as shown in the code. But this also means the `$csvdata` will keep increasing in size and that means it will have a memory footprint which can grow to be megabytes or even more.

Is there any way to dump this data to CSV, empty `$csvdata` variable without affecting the results? Hope this makes sense.

Comment: `script ends due to some error or something` - what exactly happens? I thought PowerShell continues the script by default after encountering an error.

Comment: It doesn't actually end with error. I mean i am saving the CSV file within the loop each time so that if program exits unexpectedly, i still have data in the csv file. If i export the csv after the loop then there may be a chance i lose data in such behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: the code you have in your current question is odd as it will keep overwriting the file at every pass with all the data that was already there. With a small data set you might not have noticed but it is bad nonetheless. Read on to see what you could have done instead.

> But this also means the $csvdata will keep increasing in size and that means it will have a memory footprint which can grow to be megabytes or even more.

There are a couple of issues here. First is how you are building `$csvdata`. Using `+=` will destroy the array and remake it one element larger. This is a costly operation and creates a performance issue. You should be able to use the pipeline to accomplish what you need (based on what little we see here.)

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $source | foreach{

    New-Object PSObject -Property @{FileName=$_.FullName;DateAccessed=($_.LastAccessTime).ToShortDateString()} | 
        $csvdata | Export-Csv $dest -NoTypeInformation -Append

    $count+=1
    $count
}
```

You have no reason to store `$csvdata` so don't bother doing it. Moving on to your other source of woe.

If you must store it and you expect large data sets consider using the .Net arraylist type instead. *Really* basic example in use

```
$csvData  = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

0..9 | ForEach-Object{
    [void]($csvData.Add([pscustomobject]@{Number=$_;Even=!($_%2)}))
}

$csvData | ExportTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

> there is a possibility I might lose data if script ends due to some error or something.

This is the main reason you have asked your question it seems. You are worried about data loss during the process. I will have to be vague working with your example but you are trying to fix the wrong problem I think. Instead of trying to find a more resilient export process you should be worrying about error handling.

If there is the potential for code failure you should consider using [`try{}catch{}`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell/) blocks as well as the common cmdlets parameter for [`-ErrorAction`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell/). The both have their place depending on if you are dealing with terminating or non terminating errors.

Using those in areas of failure will prevent your entire process from being in an incomplete or questionable state.

Comment: Thanks. My question was more about the way I am exporting the data. I knew my method of $csvdata += wasn't the best but that was the only way I knew it will work. You have given the perfect solution for it with the -Append keyword. Thank you very much.

Comment: To give you an example of how much difference this little change has made, when I ran it before the update it took more than 3 hours to get to 25,000 files. After the change it went over 25,000 in 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a partial export-csv, but you could just write comma separated values as a string and append them to the file inside the loop:

```
$dest="C:\users\Administrator\Documents\filelist.csv"
$csvdata=@()
$source="x:\"
$count=0

"FileName,DateAccessed" | Set-Content $dest

Get-ChildItem -Recurse $source | foreach{

    "$($_.FullName),$($_.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString())" | Add-Content $dest

$count+=1
$count
}
```